# Linq query with too many includes exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using EF6 and I have a query that selects only one entity from the database but with including all of the related entities.
I am selecting only one using FirstOrDefault() method but sometimes this exception appears

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.

Here is the code that causes the issue

```
return All()
                .Include(p => p.Location)
                .Include(m => m.Bookings)
                .Include(p => p.Links)
                .Include(p => p.Links1)
                .Include(p => p.Details)
                .Include(p => p.Details.Select(x => x.Diagnostic))
                .Include(p => p.Alerts)
                .Include(p => p.Allergies)
                .Include(p => p.Allergies.Select(x => x.List.ListCategory))
                .Include(p => p.Links.Select(x => x.Link1))
                .Include(p => p.Links1.Select(x => x.Link))
                .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Id == id);
```

Comment: Can you [lazy-load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) them instead?

Comment: No, this is the business needs :(

Comment: The error smells odd.  It looks like your transaction may have been elevated to a distributed transaction - are all these queries hitting the same data source?

Comment: @RobertHarvey do you think it's a timeout issue due to the data size or what?

Comment: @Paddy, yes, the same data source

Comment: Respectfully, you haven't described a *business need* in your question; you have described an *implementation.*  The business need (whatever that is) can be solved using whatever technique you deem suitable, and the implementation you've chosen is apparently not suitable.

Comment: Did you try to profile generated query and run it in sql server?

Comment: @IvanMartinyuk: They could do that.  But the best possible performing query *has 11 joins in it.*

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with @RobertHarvey here - this is a crazy query.  Would you ever write a single query to get all this back if you weren't using an ORM?  If not, then don't do it like this...  I would suggest either attempting to rewrite this as a simpler projection or to amend your code to get the queryable and the return queryable.FirstOrDefault().  Hover over the queryable to see the generated SQL - if your 'requirements' need it to happen like this, I would go back with the SQLand ask the person that set them if this was what they wanted.

Comment: You can also see the output query EF is generating by outputting it to the console and inspecting it. Assuming your DbContext is named `context`, try doing `context.Database.Log = s => Console.WriteLine(s);`

Comment: You'll need to expand out the code in question because from that exception it smells something like a race condition with the state of your DbContext. What does `All()` return, an `IQueryable<T>`? What represents the scope of the DbContext that `All()` and this code is relying on?  One very ugly line of code with 12 joins or so may be where the exception comes up, but likely isn't the cause of the exception.